# How to delete extension completely

Tags: error, database

I tried to install ADDTHISS social networks extension, on first attempt it installed successfully but it was not working properly so I tried re-installing. Now if I try installation, I am getting this error:

./app/code/community/AddThis/SharingTool/Block/Share.php' already exists

and ADMIN panel and Website shows ERROR 503, Error 503 was maintenance.flag and I can get website back. How should I remove this extension completely so that I can reinstall it again.

Comment: delete all file and folder /app/code/community/AddThis and delete maintenance.flag

Comment: I did that, and its not working. Still says ALREADY EXISTS

Answer (score 2):

To completely remove an extension you will need to remove all of the files added when installing the extension.  For the extension above it looks like it's supplied in a .tgz archive so just extract this, look at the files in there and delete the same files in your install.  The extension also doesn't look like it makes any changes to the database so you don't need to worry about that.

If you want to just disable the extension (which you can do to get things up and running again before you delete the extension files), edit the extensions config file in the `app/etc/modules/` directory and change the `<active>` node from `true` to `false` and then clear at least the config cache.

Also as Amit notes, delete the maintenance.flag file from the root of your Magento install to get access back to your store.

Comment: yes, I deleted maintenance FLAG file, I did it before. I have access to website. Just want to install this extension and make it work. Will try removing all files one by one.

Comment: I would advise you to fully remove the extension as per the above, then turn off compilation and disable caching, reinstall then clear (yes clear it even thought its disabled) and re-enable the cache, then re-enable compilation if was enabled before.  You will need also to log out and back into admin to be able to access extension settings.

Comment: I just noticed I have this extension on the list in MAGENTO CONNECT, but can't see settings from CONFIGURATION tab. when I installed it fist, there were some setting and this extension was on left menu bar

Comment: By all means remove from connect if you can, if not use the above instructions.

Comment: I cleared cache and reindexed everything, Why settings are not visible, I did it the same way as I did fist time.

Comment: No idea but something you are doing can't be right.  If the above answers the question, i.e. delete the extension completely can you mark it as accepted?  If you have an installation problem maybe start a new question, but essentially disable caching and compilation -> install -> clear and enable cache -> re-enable compilation (if it was enabled) -> log out and back into admin.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Login with your Magento admin panel.

Step 2: Go to system>> packge and extension >> Magento-connect.

Step 3: Log in with details

Step 4: At last before terminal you can see the add this  extension list.

Step 5: In dropdown select uninstall and click on submit.

Step 6: Magento automatic remove your extension.

Let ke know if any comments.

Comment: It asks for CHANNEL, Description Summary  and so on, where should I get all this info?

Comment: I don't believe this will work, I don't think it was installed via connect?

Comment: at fist I installed it via Connect, and it installed properly, but was not working, than uninstalled via connect and then when tried to install again, it says file already exists.

Comment: Then check your package.xml. You will find all files

Comment: This will not drop SQL tables

Comment: I managed to uninstall and reinstall it, Thank you guys

Comment: Grate you can mark answer as corect.